# Mbaas for hybrid app (with cordova)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps, mbaas

I'm starting a new mobile hybrid application with cordova and i want to use an mbaas to accelerate development process. I need:

- Database
- Authentication (with social logins)
- Push notifications sent from client
- Server-side scripting (optional)

I've seen Firebase, but it's a little bit tricky for push notifications (i have to create another server) and also it don't support very well the hybrid applications.
Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mbaas like [built.io's backend](https://www.built.io/products/backend/overview), I am not sure if they support server side scripting but rest all can be achived.
You can refer to their docs https://docs.built.io/
Refer to this feature list https://www.built.io/products/backend/features